Light fixture works after flip switch multiple times
I have a ceiling fixture with long fluorescent bulbs in the kitchen. Not sure how old it is, but going to guess 20 years.
There are two wall switches connected to it. There is one wall switch that often has to be flipped multiple times to turn the light on. It doesn't always require multiple flips, but I can't tell what conditions make it so that multiple flips are needed. That same switch has no problem turning off the light with just one flip. The other switch works fine.
I know nothing about wiring. If I replace the irregular switch, do I have to do anything with the other switch?

Two switches for one light mean they are three way switches.  Three screws and wires on each switch.  Take pictures before removing any wires.

Some fluorescent fixtures won't start reliably unless the metal case is connected to ground. Flipping the power on/off many times can get them to work. If the fixture is not grounded, try grounding it.

There are two common ways to wire a two-way switch. The same type of switch is used in either circuit, SPDT (single pole, double throw).
Since this is an older house, most likely it's using the first schematic shown. Unless there is major rewiring to be done, likely you can keep the original connection scheme, being "grandfathered" in most locales' codes.

Remove power at the fuse/breaker box.
Remove the faulty switch and take a picture of it, to show the current wiring.
Take the picture or switch, itself, to a hardware store to get a replacement, hopefully with the same terminal layout as the old.
Connect the new switch as the old one was.

BTW, when the fluorescent tubes fail, consider replacing with LED tubes, particularly those not using the old ballast, for increased efficiency, longer service life and better color balance. It's an easy DIY fix. (The whole fixture could be replaced with a one-piece LED lamp, too.)
